# Facebook Python login script not using API

Tags: python, facebook, urllib2

Ok, so I found a basic script to log in to facebook using python a while back. It didn't work - but after some tweaking (mainly around updating the post strings) it worked well for quite a while. Now it's stopped again - I suspect because facebook have changed their site a little.

I've tried making further tweaks having captured a login in Firefox and making sure I mimic as many of the post values etc as possible.

I need to log in to the site directly as I have a bunch of scripts that collect data that's available through a browser, but not through the API.

Having spent days trying to fix this I'm still drawing a blank... what am I missing?

```
import sys
import re
import urllib
import urllib2
import cookielib
import json

def main():
    # Check the arguments
    user = sys.argv[1]
    passw = sys.argv[2]

    # Initialize the needed modules
    CHandler = urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cookielib.CookieJar())
    browser = urllib2.build_opener(CHandler)

    browser.addheaders = [('Referer', 'http://login.facebook.com'),
                        ('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'),
                        ('User-Agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.9.1.7) Gecko/20091221 Firefox/3.5.7 (.NET CLR 3.5.30729)')]

    urllib2.install_opener(browser)
    res = browser.open('http://m.facebook.com/index.php')
    pg=res.read()
    mxt = re.search('name="li" value="(\w+)"', pg)
    mxt2 = re.search('name="m_ts" value="(\w+)"', pg)
    mxt3 = re.search('name="lsd" value="(\w+)"', pg)
    mxt4 = re.search('name="locale" value="(\w+)"', pg)

    li = mxt.group(1)
    m_ts = mxt2.group(1)
    lsd = mxt3.group(1)
    locale = mxt4.group(1)
    res.close()

    # Initialize the POST data
    data = urllib.urlencode({
        'lsd'               : lsd,
        'charset_test'      : urllib.unquote_plus('%E2%82%AC%2C%C2%B4%2C%E2%82%AC%2C%C2%B4%2C%E6%B0%B4%2C%D0%94%2C%D0%84'),
        'version'           : '1',
        'm_ts'              : m_ts,
        'li'                : li,
        'locale'            : locale,
        'signup_layout'     : 'header_button',
        'laststage'         :'first',
        'post_form_id'      : pfi,
        'email'             : user,
        'pass'              : passw,
        'login'             : 'Log in'
    })

    url='https://login.facebook.com/login.php?login_attempt=1&non_com_login=&'+ data
    res = urllib2.urlopen(url)
    print ('%s' % url)

    res.close()

    # Get Access Token
    res = browser.open('http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api')
    conft = res.read()

    # For Debugging
    fh = open('debug.html', 'w')
    fh.write(conft)
    fh.close

    mat = re.search('access_token=(.*?)"', conft)
    acct = mat.group(1)
    print ('Using access token: %s' % acct)
```

Comment: I recommend converting this from `urllib2` to `mechanize`, and `re` to `BeautifulSoup`.

Comment: Thanks - have just re-written the first part in mechanize and bosh - it works. Much better than urllib2. Many thanks.

Comment: For the record, here is the working answer for the above.
    `#!/usr/bin/python`

    `import mechanize`

    `browser = mechanize.Browser()`
    `browser.set_handle_robots(False)`
    `cookies = mechanize.CookieJar()`

    `browser.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US)     AppleWebKit/534.7 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/7.0.517.41 Safari/534.7')]`
    `browser.open("http://m.facebook.com/")`
    `browser.select_form(nr=0)`

    `browser.form['email'] = 'YOUR_LOGIN'`
    `browser.form['pass'] = 'YOUR_PASSWORD'`
    `response = browser.submit()`

Comment: Oh my, that reads much nicer, even in the comments. For the record, comments are for discussing the original post, if you're the original poster, and are addressing the post's content...consider editing the post itself. I would tack your new code on as an update. Did you try out BeautifulSoup yet? Works much nicer than parsing the HTML via the `re` module.

Comment: you have to handle if user enable email notification and also sms notification(Security Settings) scenarios too.

Answer (score 4):

For the record, here is the working answer for the above.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import mechanize

browser = mechanize.Browser()
browser.set_handle_robots(False)
cookies = mechanize.CookieJar()

browser.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US)     AppleWebKit/534.7 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/7.0.517.41 Safari/534.7')]
browser.open("http://m.facebook.com/")
browser.select_form(nr=0)

browser.form['email'] = 'YOUR_LOGIN'
browser.form['pass'] = 'YOUR_PASSWORD'
response = browser.submit()
```